# MySQL 8.0 and Windows 2022 server password mess

Tags: mysql

A few days ago I just could not connect to mySQL.Invalid password etc.So I reinstalled MySQL, set password again, restored my data from backup.It was fine for a day or two.And than it's again "invalid password".Looks like "somebody" is changing my root password within a day or two.Are there any log files to check ?

I expected that my password and privilages on my SQL will stay "unchanged".
Os:Windows server 2022,MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Does this post help you ? [Mysql cli client password keep changing automatically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/332139/my-mysql-command-line-client-password-keeps-changing-automatically-i-dont-use)